# Java pathing foreach loop

Tags: java, foreach, path-finding

I'm trying to get my "Monsters" to move through an arraylist of "PathingCoordinates", by setting the individual Monsters "chasePoint".
But everytime I add more then 1 monster, they run around the JPanel in all sorts of directions. (My guess; taking the fastest route to the next "chasePoint")

Since I'm new to java, and first time user of the foreach loop, I'd appriciate if someone would point me in the direction where my logic fails.

```
for (Monster i : Monstre) 
    {
        this.add(i); //Adds all monsters from the "Monstre" arrayList
        i.setBounds(i.monsterx, i.monstery, Monster.img0.getIconWidth(), Monster.img0.getIconHeight());


        if(i.monstery == i.chasePoint.getY() && i.monsterx == i.chasePoint.getX() ){
            p++;
            i.chasePoint = PathingCoordinates.get(p);
        }
        if(i.monsterx < i.chasePoint.getX()){
            i.monsterx++;
        }else if(i.monstery < i.chasePoint.getY()){
            i.monstery++;
        }else if(i.monsterx > i.chasePoint.getX()){
            i.monsterx--;
        }else if(i.monstery > i.chasePoint.getY()){
            i.monstery--;
        }
    }
```

Apologies if more info is needed, please request.

Edit: There's a delay between each monster spawn. First monster chases the correct "chasePoint" next mobs, seems to move randomly.

Comment: I assume there's a problem with a global variable p. Can you post the whole class?

Comment: How is chase point set, this could be "spooky action at a distance" where you accidentally set the same object within the constructor of the moster, but we need to see the whole class (which preferably has its own main method that allows it to run independantly of other classes and shows the problem)

Comment: Indeed there seems to be a problem with the "p" variable! brb

Comment: Do I understand correctly that each monster should follow the same path (one after the other)? In that case, `p` should be a member variable of `Monster`, rather than a global shared by all monsters.

Comment: Problem was the "p" variable was created in the wrong place. Thanks for the help guys! : )

Answer (score 0):

Created variable "p" in the Monster-Class definition
Credits goes to Lolsvemir & Heuster.